# RMD after annuitizing an annuity in a traditional IRA

Tags: united-states, ira, withdrawal, annuity, rmd

I live in the United States and I have an annuity that hasn't been annuitized in a traditional IRA account (IRA A).

I need to take a required minimum distribution (RMD) of $8K this year for IRA A.

I have a few other traditional IRA's which I'll lump together (IRA B) which have a RMD of $17K.

I've already taken out $10K from IRA A this year.  If I annuitize IRA A this year, it will pay out $7K this year.

How much do I still need to take out from IRA B if I annuitize IRA A this year?  I'm assuming that the annuity payment this year will count towards IRA A's RMD, so I still need to withdraw $8K - 7K = 1K.  IRA B's RMD = $17K.  Then I subtract $10K, the money I've already taken out of IRA A.

1K + 17K - 10K = 8K

Do I need to take $8K out of IRA B?  Thanks.

Comment: IRAs that are invested in annuities have so complicated rules regarding RMDs that the IRS does not bother even trying to explain them. Publication 590b simply says _"If your traditional IRA is an individual retirement annuity, special rules apply to figuring the required minimum distribution. For more information on rules for annuities, see Regulations section 1.401(a)(9)-6. These regulations can be read in many libraries, IRS offices, and online at IRS.gov."_ Thus, I expect that you won't receive an answer here.